# Весьма сложный запрос MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Вообщем поскольку я не особо силён в сложных запросах sql нужна ваша помощь. Есть 3 таблицы выглядят так:

1. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так и мне из этих таблиц нужно сделать такой запрос: Выведите  имена клиентов и количество их заказов, созданных  в апреле 2016 года и содержащих один или больше товаров из списка (id: 151515,151617,151514), отсортируйте результат по убыванию суммы заказа.

Я смог сделать такое:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT c.name, count(o.id) AS count_order FROM clients c LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.clients_id 
LEFT JOIN products p ON o.id = p.order_id WHERE o.ctime >= :date1 AND o.ctime <= :date2 AND p.id = :p_id1 OR p.id = :p_id2 OR p.id = :p_id3 GROUP BY c.name");
$stmt->execute(array('date1' => $date1, 'date2' => $date2, 'p_id1' => 151515, 'p_id2' => 151617, 'p_id3' => 151514));

$clients = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $clients[] = $row;
}
```

Вообщем осталось только ввести сортировку по сумме заказа, как сделать сортировку я знаю, но вычислять сумму?

Comment: У вас ошибка в WHERE. Условие `p.id = :p_id1 OR p.id = :p_id2 OR p.id = :p_id3` должно быть заключено в круглые скобки.

Comment: Описания таблиц лучше вставлять текстом.

Comment: Задавая вопрос чисто по SQL, не надо в нём размещать код на других языках (в данном случае PHP) - поправьте. И замените фотографии на текстовые DDL. Сумма вычисляется агрегатной функцией SUM()  при соответствующей группировке.

Answer (score 0):

```
" select name, count_order from
  (  SELECT distinct c.name
                 , count(o.id) AS count_order
                 , sum(p.price) sumprice 
     FROM clients c 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.clients_id 
LEFT JOIN products p ON o.id = p.order_id 
    WHERE o.ctime >= :date1 AND o.ctime <= :date2 AND (p.id = :p_id1 OR p.id = :p_id2 
       OR p.id = :p_id3) GROUP BY c.name)
order by sumprice"
```

Если сортировать по сумме заказа

Comment: Данный запрос, во-первых, выводит не полную сумму заказа, а только по строкам с тремя указанными товарами. во вторых, отсев по датам идет только для первого товара. Для второго и третьего даты не фильтруются.

Comment: Я взял его запрос и ответил на суть. Как отсортировать.